# What does the hidden class do in React-Helmet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I have seen someone use `<Helmet bodyAttributes={{class: 'hidden'}}/>` and have no idea what the class 'hidden' does? Can someone please explain it?Thanks
PS: I am using react-helmet in gatsby.js

Answer (score -1):

`bodyAttributes` is a prop that sets html attributes on the `body` element. That is apparently setting an attribute `class="hidden"` (see [this issue](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/300)).

Comment: Gotta love Stack Overflow, where you get downvoted for answering the question and providing a source.

Answer (score -1):

Classes don't do anything unless some other CSS or JS (or other programming language) is written to target them.